# Button is enabled false default background and text color

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

[image]

How can I get the default background and text color when the button is enabled is false ?

Comment: Just use MaterialButton from the material design library and you are good to go

Comment: I just want to know the background and text color code when the button is disabled

Comment: Access its properties in the code section

Comment: I didn't found any information about it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation what you are looking for :
https://material.io/components/buttons/android#text-button

Open the website and there you will find various attributes for the Text Label , Container and Icon . For your case you can use the getColor / setColor properties in your code and do the needful as per your needs .

Answer (score 0):

Using this code to get color (hex value) from the state of a view:

```
int color = yourButton.getBackgroundTintList().getColorForState(
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, //enabel
                    -android.R.attr.state_enabled},  //disable
            0 //color value if there is no match state values
    );
String hexColor = String.format("#%08X", color);
```

The color you get back will be the first state it finds, or default color that you have specified (0 in my case). You can do the same to get any state color of text in button.